# array_search_recursive() .. help me find where value exists in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

the following function nicely tells me if value is found or not in array ..

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        if (is_array($value) && array_search_recursive($needle, $value)) return true;
        else if ($value == $needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but i want that array index number where the value exits in the array.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but I think you'd need to do a standard for (if there is one in PHP) so that you always have the index. But even in that manner you'd only get the top array, not the final one, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your function by adding a third parameter passed by reference.

The function will return true if the needle found. Also, the $indexes is an array of indexes to the found value.

```
function array_search_recursive($needle, $haystack, &$indexes=array())
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $indexes[] = $key;
            $status = array_search_recursive($needle, $value, $indexes);
            if ($status) {
                return true;
            } else {
                $indexes = array();
            }
        } else if ($value == $needle) {
            $indexes[] = $key;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
$haystack1 = array(
    0 => 'Sample 1',
    1 => 'Sample 2',
    2 => array(
        'Key' => 'Sample 3',
        1 => array(
            0 => 'Sample 4',
            1 => 'Sample 5'
        )
    ),
    4 => 'Sample 6',
    3 => array(
        0 => 'Sample 7'
        ),
);
```

The indexes to "Sample 5" are [2][1][1].

```
if (array_search_recursive('Sample 5', $haystack1, $indexes)) {
/**
 * Output
 * Array
 * (
 *      [0] => 2
 *      [1] => 1
 *      [2] => 1
 * )
 */
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($indexes);
    echo '</pre>';
    die;
}
```