# How can I find the value of a certain key hidden somewhere in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to write a method in PHP which is iterating through a maybe multidimensional array and gives me back the value of the key "user_id", which can be anywhere in that array. 
If it cannot be found I guess "false" would be a proper output.

My fist tray is a array_walk_recursive($myarray, 'searchUserId' ), but I wonder how I will get that value back from the callback method to my method which should return the found value.

This is what I tried so far:

Example array:

```
$myarray = array('id'   => 6,
    'foo'  => 7,
    'User' => array(
        'id'   => 1,
        'baa' => 'kiki',
    ),
    'Baz' => array(
        'user_id' => 1,
        'foo'    => 'kiki',
    ));
```

First try at a solution:

```
function searchUserId($value, $key)
{
    if ($key == 'user_id')
        echo "$value\n<br>";
}

array_walk_recursive($myarray, 'searchUserId');a
```

This call back DOES find the key and ecos the correct value. But I don't want it echoed I want is somehow given back to me as a single result.

As always any help and hints are appreciated!

Calamity Jane

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232497/array-search-recursive-help-me-find-where-value-exists-in-multidimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a variable by reference, allowing us to alter it.

```
$strReturn = "";
array_walk_recursive($myarray, function($element, $key) use(&$strReturn) {
   if($key === 'user_id') {  // strict comparison will ensure no accident `0` key matches
       $strReturn = $element;
   }
});
echo $strReturn;
```

#### For example

If I have the following array;

```
Array
(
    [location] => y
    [animal] => zebra
    [user_info] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
        )

)
```

`$strReturn` will have the value `1`.

Comment: sorry, it looks like I can only mark one answer as successful, although both are.

Comment: So.... I just discovered, that the solution above gives me back a boolean true or the mentioned error in the comments and yours gives me back the actual value.

So your solution has won. But if anyone can share some insight why this difference occurs although both solutions looke very similar I would be glad.

Comment: By the way I noticed the difference when testing with an array which had user_id = 2

Comment: I have edited this answer, not because it is wrong but because it is better practice to use a strict comparison on `$key`.  PHP's "type juggling" caught me out once and wasted hours of my time figuring out what was magically going wrong!  Here's a [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d241f9b68c565305dbfdbddf71e2732ed2565221)  Here's my related question (which was quite a face-palming moment): [Type juggling while making loose comparison yields unwanted result
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426990/type-juggling-while-making-loose-comparison-yields-unwanted-result)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Pass it a user variable by reference and then access that value:
(I changed the user_id to something more distinguishable so I'd know it was working correctly.)

```
$myarray = array('id'   => 6,
    'foo'  => 7,
    'User' => array(
        'id'   => 1,
        'baa' => 'kiki',
    ),
    'Baz' => array(
        'user_id' => 199,
        'foo'    => 'kiki',
    ));

function searchUserId($value, $key, &$myvar)
{
    if ($key == 'user_id')
        $myvar= "$value\n<br>";
}

array_walk_recursive($myarray, 'searchUserId',&$myvar);
echo $myvar;
```

Comment: I tried this and got "Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed"

Comment: Hey guys, this was fast! And it works, too....

I was wondering whatfor this third parameter was, but the explanation in the manual was not compatible with my understanding ;)

Comment: @Pattle, It worked for me here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ but I did not try it on my server.